# Hi - Pakistani citizen, travelling from Pakistan to Caymans Island via Cuba (Havana). Please confirm if i need a visa

Tags: transit-visas

Pakistani citizen, travelling from Pakistan to Caymans Island via Cuba (Havana). Please confirm if i need a visa.

Comment: For Cuba? Or Cayman? Will you transit airside? AFAIK *all** visitors to Cuba require a visa, you can apply here http://visasonline.cubaminrex.cu/en

Comment: That depends on a LOT of details: Put your exact details into https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/passport-visa-health-travel-document-requirements.htm

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Seeing as this is tagged transit-visa, that this is specifically about Cuba, as a question about a visa to the Caymans would not be a transit-visa....